# How to plot or show multiple images in a row using julia?

Tags: image, julia, annotate, julia-plots

I'm new to Julia and I used MNIST handwritten digit train data to get multiple images in matrix with size `28 x 28`. Let's assume I store them in array `img[i]` with length n(n is dynamic). I want to show Images in one window such that every image has its own specific label under it.

I tried to search and read documents, currently I use `hcat(images_window, img[i])` for all images and `plot(images_window)` and annotate some text label for each image in specific coordinates. This way is not a good practice and n is not configurable either.
I expect Julia have something like dynamic layout for its plots and I can show Image in each subplot and show them in a window with something like this:

```
plt = plot()
for (i, subplot) in enumerate(plot)
    plot!(plt, subplot, layout(i))
end
display(plt)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't mention which plotting library you are using but from the basic syntax I'm vaguely guessing that you might be asking bout `Plots.jl`.

In `Plots`, plotting multiple subplots on one figure in principle works like this:

```
using Plots

p1 = plot(rand(5))

p2 = plot(rand(5))

plot(p1, p2)
```

i.e., you call `plot` with multiple arguments which themselves are plots. You can then additionally specify a `layout` kwarg, which in its simplest form takes a tuple of `(nrows, ncols)` and places the subplots in a grid with the specified number of rows and columns.

As an example, here's three plots next to each other:

```
plot(plot.([rand(5) for _ ∈ 1:3])..., layout = (1, 3))
```

[image]